# MyBatis SELECT query with IF condition

Tags: sql, mybatis

I have a table **sample_table** like this

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------------+
| pkey1 | pkey2 | mode  | type  | type_number |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------------+
|   001 |    01 | light | type1 |        1234 |
|   001 |    02 | light | type2 |        2345 |
|   002 |    01 | dark  | type1 |        3456 |
|   002 |    02 | dark  | type2 |        4567 |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------------+
```

I have a **MyBatis** SELECT query pseudo-code like this

```
SELECT 
 Master.pkey1,
 Master.pkey2,
 Master.mode,
 Master.type,
 T1.selectedNumber type_number
FROM
( SELECT * from sample_table)
 as Master
left join (select type_number as selectedNumber from sample_table where type='type1') as T1
ON T1.pkey1 = Master.pkey1
left join (select type_number as selectedNumber from sample_table where type='type2') as T2
ON T2.pkey1 = Master.pkey1)
```

Is there a way to select from T1 or T2 based on the value in mode, like

```
SELECT 
 Master.pkey1,
 Master.pkey2,
 Master.mode,
 Master.type,
 if Master.type='light'
  T1.selectedNumber type_number
 if Master.type='dark'
  T2.selectedNumber type_number
```

My expected result is something like this

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------------+
| pkey1 | pkey2 | mode  | type  | type_number |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------------+
|   001 |    01 | light | type1 |        1234 |
|   001 |    02 | light | type2 |        1234 |
|   002 |    01 | dark  | type1 |        4567 |
|   002 |    02 | dark  | type2 |        4567 |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------------+
```

Edit: Added Some extra code and the expected result

Comment: (1) Show the results that you want.  (2) Your pseudo code as joins but no join conditions.

Comment: hi, I have updated the question

Answer (score 0):

How about just using window functions?

```
select s.*,
       (case when mode = 'light'
             then max(case when type = 'type1' then type_number end) over (partition by pkey1)
             else max(case when type = 'type2' then type_number end) over (partition by pkey2)
       end)
from sample_table s;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. But I cannot change the existing structure. Is there a way to include this logic in the code pseudo-code I initially shared?